# How do you use a background.html page (instead of background.js) with Manifest 2 in a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension that worked great with the background specified as a script (background.js). Chrome created a virtual background.html page...

I need to a script to background (to get Google Drive integration) and so (as I understand it) need to move to background.html.

My Manifest now specifies:

```
"background": {
   "page": "background.html"},
```

I added "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" to my original setup (below) to gain Google Drive access for my Chrome Extension...but my background page was throwing "gapi is not defined" errors...so I switched to background.html to try and get my background processes to be able to access the Drive scripts.

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["/dscripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js","/dscripts/firebase.js","/dscripts/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js","/dscripts/bootstrap.min.js", "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js", "/scripts/background.js"]},
```

My new background.html page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Original javascript / CDN -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dscripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dscripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dscripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dscripts/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- FIREBASE  - I think we only need JS, not app.js and auth.js -->
    <script src="dscripts/firebase.js"></script>

    <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script> -->

    <!-- Google APIS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

    <!-- background.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/background.js">

  </head>
</html>
```

I haven't made any changes to background.js - which holds **chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener** and lots of well-established logic.

When I run my Extension and view the background.html console, I get:
Navigated to chrome-extension://XXXXX/background.html

Usually there would be a ton of debug console content generated by my background.js file. It's as if the background.js doesn't run.

Which makes sense, I guess - there's no dom to load and trigger actions.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious (apologies) - but all the examples I could find use background.js, not background.html.

How do I get my javascript to fire when specifying background.html?

Comment: Why using background.html instead of listing your scripts in the manifest?

Comment: Specific to the https://apis.google.com/js/api.js, which I had in CSP, I was getting "GAPI is not defined" messages...so I thought by creating a background.html page I would be able to get it working...

Major regrets...nothing is working now:) I have no idea (aside from rollback) how to get a basic background.js thing going again...

Comment: Well, it's hard to say without seeing the code, but I don't think that changing from listing all the scripts to using a background.html would do anything. I mean, the background.html page gets automatically generated anyway, so...

Comment: I can't find the reference...but earlier, as I was trying to solve the original problem, I came across documentation that said you would use a background.html page if you wanted to use external JS...something like that.

Assume the simplest of situations...if you switch to .html rather than .js, how do you get the actual javascript to fire? Do you have to use chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage() in each additional js file that wants to use the background page?

Comment: I see what you're talking about... I usually always download the scripts and add them in the manifest rather than relying on external resources, so I don't really know. You should still be able to use `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()`, I don't see why you shouldn't.

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: On what planet is linking to CSP helpful? My question is: how do you use background.html (page) instead of background.js (script). Now that I've switched to a background page my code doesn't run. 

I guess there's some sort of kick-off required - the equivalent of $(document).ready. But there's no DOM...so I just don't understand how to get the javascript associated with the background.html to run.

Answer (score 1):

Was missing closing  tag on the background.js file. Once I added that then the js in background ran exactly as expected.

So there is no extra action (for those coming after) required to use your own background.html page vs. the auto-generated one.